# Persist an Entity in a collection and embedded in other object

Tags: java, mongodb, hibernate, jpa

> I want to persist ina a MongoDB an object in more than one place using Hibernate OGM. For example, i have:

```
@Entity
class User {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator="uuid")
  @GenericGenerator(name="uuid", strategy="uuid2")
  private String id

  String name
  String password
  int age 
  String nickname
}
```

> This mapped any object User in a collection of users. But I have a Loan class:

```
@Entity()
class Loan {
  @Id 
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
  @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")  
  private String id

  @Embedded
  User user

  String bookName
}
```

It seems JPA doesn't allow put `@Entity` and `@Embbedable` annotation at the same time. I want to store the user information in a collection but when I want to recover Loan I need to do in only one query to recover the Loan and entire User data.

Is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: What you are looking for is most probably a One-To-One relationship. [The official Java EE 8 JPA tutorial](https://javaee.github.io/tutorial/persistence-intro002.html#BNBQH) has a good explanation at how to use it.

Comment: I usee One-toOne relation but the problem is in the Loan collection. It stores the user_id and not the full nested object. Besides, is not One-to-One because one user may have a lot of loans, right?

Comment: If each `User` has multiple `Loan`s and each `Loan` has exactly one `User`, then the `User`-object should have a `@OneToMany`-annotated field `Set<Loan> loans` and the `Loan`-object should have a `@ManyToOne`-annotated field `User user`. Mapping is job of hibernate.

Comment: Yes, it works but only with the Id of each entity in the other. I want to nest the entire User in a Loan. Besides it makes a bidirectional relationship and i don't want to. I need to access the user in one query, and later when i get a Loan i need recover the full information of the user nested in the register.

That i was asking is if i could make denormalization with Hibernate OGM.

Thanks Turing85!

Comment: You do not necessarily need the `@OneToMany`-annotation in `User` since the `@ManyToOne`-annotated collection in `Loan` is the owning side. The "nesting" is done by hibernate, but for this, you need a relationship. Otherwise, if you insist on embedding a `User` in `Loan`, `User` must not be an `@Entity`.

Comment: Yes, nesting is simulated by Hibernate. But it make a few queries to the DB to recover the data because Mongo doesn't have Joins. It's a matter of performance. I want only one query to the database to recover the full data.  
If User must not be an @Entity i can't store it in another collection and i can't recover it in only one query to the DB.

Comment: Well... maybe don't use a document db then? There is no free lunch. What you explained so far seems a perfect fit for traditional SQL databases.

Comment: Yes, there's no free lunch but like i said, it's a matter of performance. Documents DB may be sharded and Relational Databases not!. Both storage types resolve the problem but has different properties.